# how should we combine coverage criteria?

Tags: testing, branch, code-coverage, criteria

I was reading about coverage criteria. In this paper [How Effective Are Code Coverage Criteria?](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/7272926/)

I read that the combination of statement, branch, MC/DC and loop coverage has a better result than using any of them as a single criteria (combining several control-flow coverage together is better than the strongest criterion alone).

I don't know how  they combine them.
anybody knows how should we combine for example two single coverage criteria?
I read somewhere that they use the result of a coverage criteria to use it in another coverage criteria. but I can't find the source, therefore I am not sure either it is true or not?
and also is this the meaning of combination of coverage criteria or not?

Answer (score 0):

There are many structural code coverage metric definitions available. And to answer question: If one method subsumes the other, there is no need to employ the less powerfull coverage method. This means, there is no need to combine them all.

For example, please check the linked NASA document:

[MCDC](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20010057789.pdf)

It contains an overview for some methods, which subsume others.

See for example one table from the above document:

[image: Coverage Criterion]

Copyright: NASA

There is no need to do a Decision Coverage check, if you are already doing MCDC. That is different with additional measures, like function coverage or loop coverage. If they will give additional benefit to you is hard to tell. Obiously the study mentioned by you, indicates that.

What you need to understand, is that you should not do "structural testing". You should do a requirements based test (or use other methods) and then measure a certain defined Coverage. In your test strategy, you need to define, what coverage measurements should be done and what coverage percentage must be achieved. If the excpected coverage is not reached, then you need to add more test cases.

If you ask for recomendations on what to use, you should follow the very strong requirements given by the FAA and in ISO26262. They recomend for the highest safety class (e.g. ASIL D)  MCDC. By following this strict requirement, you maybe can forget about other methods.

Unfortunately tools for deriving tests cases and especially measuring the resulting coverage are expensive and need often code instrumentation.

If you are interested in MCDC, you may want to look at 
[MCDC](https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/MCDC)